# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apscheduler'

Tags: python-3.x, apscheduler, octoprint

it might be a silly problem.

I have no idea about why I am facing `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apscheduler'` but I have already successfully installed APscheduler.

I have tried uninstalling it and re-install the specific version of APscheduler, but it didn't work.
I also tried installing it on virtualenv, but it didn't work as well.

Python:
|      pip: 20.3.3
|      version: 3.7.3
OS: Linux (Ubuntu 20.04)

```html
from __future__ import absolute_import
import octoprint.plugin
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient, Point
import requests

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.backgroundScheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
```

logging as follows:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/oprint/lib/python3.7/site-packages/octoprint/plugin/core.py", line 1298, in _import_plugin
    module = _load_module(module_name, spec)
  File "/home/pi/oprint/lib/python3.7/site-packages/octoprint/plugin/core.py", line 69, in _load_module
    return imp.load_module(name, f, filename, details)
  File "/home/pi/oprint/lib/python3.7/site-packages/octoprint/vendor/imp.py", line 238, in load_module
    return load_package(name, filename)
  File "/home/pi/oprint/lib/python3.7/site-packages/octoprint/vendor/imp.py", line 212, in load_package
    return _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/pi/oprint/lib/python3.7/site-packages/octoprint_CMfgDataAcquisition/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apscheduler'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obTxb.png)

APscheduler == 3.6.3 has been installed.

Comment: are you running the same python which you used to install the module? sometimes a device may have multiple python interpreters installed. module may be installed for a different python than which is being used for coding

Answer (score 3):

This was also posted to APScheduler's bug tracker (as a feature request no less), and it contained critical information not given here on SO: the output of `sudo pip install APScheduler==3.6.3`:
[image]

As you can see from the path (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages), OP was installing it on Python 3.8 and then trying to import it from Python 3.7.

The solution is to use Python 3.7 to install it: `python3.7 -m pip install APScheduler==3.6.3`. Note, however, that 3.6.3 is not the latest release.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use sudo when installing modules with pip.
If you have already setup a virtualenv, activate it and then install your dependencies without sudo

```
source {YOUR_VENV}/bin/activate    
pip install APscheduler==3.6.3
```

If you see your traceback, you're using packages from `/home/pi/oprint/lib/python3.7/site-packages/` whereas you're installing your dependencies on `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/`

Otherwise, verify your $PATH and $PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 0):

***Solved*** Same problem here. Installing with pip3 didn't work. I downloaded APScheduler from PyPi and installed it directly, same problem.

I got a hunch, I restarted my laptop, and it worked! I don't know why, I never have problems installing modules, but it works after restart... Give it a try!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).